# Circular motion in navigation stack

Tags: gazebo, navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot setup in gazebo with an empty map and using move_base for navigation. The robot if given a goal to move to within the viewing range of the kinect the robot goes straight to the goal (as it should in an empty map) But if the goal given to the robot is behind the robots back (outside the viewing range) then the robots take a circular motion trajectory towards the goal, which seems like the robot is scanning for obstacles inside an empty map. Couldn't figure out whats wrong. Any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223893/circular-motion-in-navigation-stack/) by [Usman Arif](https://answers.ros.org/users/22287/usman-arif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the robot will always keep scanning for obstacles when you send a goal. Although the static map has no obstacles, but it will keep looking for any dynamic obstacles that can come in its way.

---

Originally posted by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) with karma: 66 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usman Arif](https://answers.ros.org/users/22287/usman-arif/) on 2016-01-18**:
B2meer,
Why does this only happen when the goal assigned is not infornt of the robot.
If the goal assigned is infront of the robot it goes straight to it. no circular scannings
But if the goal assigned is not infront then it turns around and then follows this trajectory with circular motion.

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-01-18**:
in case of goal is in front of robot, the kinect is able to see and mark the area free of obstacles, whereas, in case of goal behind the robot, the robot does not know about the situation of obstacles since that area is currently not in the kinect's range, so it rotates to clear that area.